# Need to calculate the Rank and OverallRank fields from given array using JavaScript/JQuery or any other ClientSide

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, arrays

I am working with .NET application, now I want to calculate the Rank and OverallRank field from the given array In Client Side, I can able to find out the fields (Rank, OverallRank) using SQL Server, But I don’t know how to solve it in JavaScript/JQuery or any other client library.

**Given Array:**
My array represents TotalOrderLines based on SKU by ShipYear wise

var Array=[{"ShipYear":"2011","SKU":"XXX","SKUDescription":"AZ","TotOrderLines":"100"},{"ShipYear":"2012","SKU":"XXX","SKUDescription":"AZ","TotOrderLines":"324"},{"ShipYear":"2011","SKU":"YYY","SKUDescription":"AY","TotOrderLines":"300"},{"ShipYear":"2012","SKU":"YYY","SKUDescription":"AY","TotOrderLines":"300"},{"ShipYear":"2011","SKU":"ZZZ","SKUDescription":"AX","TotOrderLines":"300"},{"ShipYear":"2012","SKU":"ZZZ","SKUDescription":"AX","TotOrderLines":"424"},{"ShipYear":"2013","SKU":"ZZZ","SKUDescription":"AX","TotOrderLines":"612"}];

**Array in Table format (for easy understanding):**
**ShipYear  SKU     SKUDescription  TotOrderLines**
2011           XXX         AZ                      100
2012           XXX         AZ                      324
2011           YYY         AY                      300
2012           YYY         AY                      300
2011           ZZZ         AX                      300
2012           ZZZ         AX                      424
2013           ZZZ         AX                      612

**Logic for Rank and OverallRank:**
**Rank:**
 
I want to calculate Rank within the ShipYear, Now we can take 2011 ShipYear, here we have 3 records (TotOrderLines) respectively 100,300,300 so My output rank should be 2, 1, 1.
Now we move into 2012 ShipYear, Ranks should starts with 1, Here we have 3 records 324,300,424 so output rank should be 2, 3, 1

**OverallRank:**
OverallRank is based on Cumulative TotOrderLines based on SKU.
Step 1: we need to SUM(TotOrderLines) by SKU
**SKU      SKUDescription    TotOrderLines   OverallRank**
XXX     AZ                      424                     3
YYY     AY                      600                     2
ZZZ     AX                      1336                    1

**Expected Output:**
**ShipYear  SKU      SKUDescription    TotOrderLines   Rank    OverallRank**
2011              XXX           AZ                    100                   2                     3
2012              XXX           AZ                    324                   2                     3
2011              YYY           AY                    300                   1                     2
2012              YYY           AY                    300                   3                     2
2011              ZZZ           AX                    300                   1                     1
2012              ZZZ           AX                    424                   1                     1
2013              ZZZ           AX                    612                   1                     1

**Updated OverallRank field, Now you can better understand the logic**

Comment: `respectively 100,300,300 so My output rank should be 2, 1, 1.` whats the logic here.

Comment: There is no big logic here, Rank based on maximum orders count, Here maximum value is 300, so Rank would be 1, If we have same orders count we need to make sure same Rank, Second highest value is 100 that's why i ranked as 2, So rank should be 2,1,1. If you see my expected output then you can easily catch up the logic, Rank based on ShipYear wise and OverAllRank is SUM(TotOrderLines) by SKU wise

Comment: Well that makes the Rank clear, But your overall rank is still partial confusing, the part I am confused is in the output you have SKUDescription. Whats the logic of this description?

Comment: There is no logic behind SKUDescription in overall Rank, It just additional info I need to carry on into final result that's it

Comment: Sorry for the wrong values, Now i updated the right values in OverallRank field, Now you can check

Comment: there is no logic?? what do you mean? you have only 3 SKUDescription in the expected output of overall rank. is it sum of all the years?

Comment: Yes, you are right, It is sum of all the years by SKU wise, and we need to assign rank in desc order.